# Как переменную из одного класса передать в другой?

Tags: objective-c

Добрый день. Если кто может, помогите, пожалуйста!
У меня есть два класса:

```
ViewController, ViewController2
```

В первом классе по нажатию кнопки Button переменной string нужно присвоить значение "any_string". Я это делаю следующим образом:

```
//ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController   
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* string;

//ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize string;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (IBAction)GoToViewController2:(id)sender {

    ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:view2 animated:YES completion:nil];

- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {

    [self returnString];
}
-(NSString*)returnString
{
    string = @"any_string";
    return string;
}
@end
```

В следующем классе я создаю объект класса ViewController.

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewController *viewController=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    NSString *newString = [viewController returnString];        
}  
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Когда я ставлю breakpoint, то все получается: у меня объект newString со значением "any_string".
Но если я делаю этот следующим образом:

```
NSString* newString = viewController.string; // newString is nil
```

тогда newString оказывается пустой строкой.

Может, кто знает, как мне сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в первом классе во вотором были сохранены свойства?

Comment: @Vasil, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ну все правильно. 
Тут `[viewController returnString];`, ты у экземпляра (viewController) класса ViewController вызываешь метод 
 `returnString`. И выполняется этот код:

```
-(NSString*)returnString
{
    string = @"any_string";
    return string;
}
```

И переменной string присваивается строка.

А когда ты хочешь добраться до переменной string вот так `viewController.string;`, она будет nil, т.к. она пуста. Метод returnString не отработал.

viewController, который создается в viewController2, не имеет ничего общего с тем первым viewController, в котором ты нажимал кнопку.

Если тебе нужно передать строку из одного viewController во второй при нажатии на кнопку, нужно передавать строку при переходе во второй контроллер, а не пытаться достать строку из первого, находясь во втором. Когда ты переходишь во второй контроллер, первый уничтожается.
Нужно перенести `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* string;` во второй контроллер и при переходе передать в string нужную строку.

```
- (IBAction)GoToViewController2:(id)sender {

ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
view2.string = @"Some string";

[self presentViewController:view2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Либо если использовать метод `returnString`, то так:

```
- (IBAction)GoToViewController2:(id)sender {

ViewController2 *view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
view2.string = [self returnString];

[self presentViewController:view2 animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

P.S. Писать `@synthesize string;` сейчас не нужно. Это устаревший синтаксис. Свойства синтезируются автоматически.