# передача изменяемого массива

Tags: ios, objective-c, делегаты

Пожалуйста помогите, мучаюсь целый день. Предположим у меня есть 2 ViewController (ViewController и TwoViewController). На первом вью имеет кнопка перехода ко TwoViewController и UISegmentedControl. Я хочу вмассив NSMutableArray под индексом 0 записывать показания этого сегмент контроллера. Затем передать этот массив в TwoViewController и по нажатию кнопки на TwoViewController, менять текст lable, находящего тоже на этом же вью. В интернете полно примеров, но почему то массив мне приходит пустой. Мой код при попытке оформить это через делегаты

```
//ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol ProtocolPrint;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)go:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)segment:(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* info;
@property(weak, nonatomic) id <ProtocolPrint> delegate;

@end

@protocol ProtocolPrint
-(NSString*) print:(ViewController*) inf;
@end

 //  ViewController.m

 #import "ViewController.h"
 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.info = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
 }
 //кнопка перехода к TwoViewController
 - (IBAction)go:(UIButton *)sender {
 UIStoryboard* storyBoard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController *test = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Storyboard2"];
[self presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

 - (IBAction)segment:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
 switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        self.info[0] = @"значение 1";
        break;
    case 1:
        self.info[0] = @"значение 2";
        break;
    case 2:
        self.info[0] = @"значение 3";
        break;
    case 3:
        self.info[0] = @"значение 4";
        break;

    default:
        break;
 }
 }
 @end


//  TwoViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface TwoViewController : UIViewController <ProtocolPrint>

- (IBAction)back:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)editText:(UIButton *)sender;

@end

//  TwoViewController.m

#import "TwoViewController.h"

@interface TwoViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) ViewController *oneVC;

@end

@implementation TwoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_oneVC.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)back:(UIButton *)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)editText:(UIButton *)sender {
self.label.text = [self print:self.oneVC];
}
- (NSString *)print:(ViewController *)inf {
return inf.info[0];
}

@end
```

Пробовал решить этот вопрос через синглтон, через пример здесь

[Как переменную из одного класса передать в другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/406043/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)

и здесь

http://www.imaladec.com/forum/index.php?/topic/2046-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/

но результат один и тот же, на текст на лейбле ни чего не появляется, элемент массива [0] так и остается @"". Подскажите новичку в iOS, в чем проблемма??

Comment: Какой таблицы? во второй вью массив приходит но абсолютно пустой

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, чтобы передать данные на следующий контроллер, не нужны делегаты. Для этого в Ваше методе `- (IBAction)go:(UIButton *)sender` созданному контроллеру присваиваете необходимые данные. Ну и для таких целей достаточно `NSString`:

```
- (IBAction)go:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIStoryboard* storyBoard =  [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    TwoViewController *test = (TwoViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Storyboard2"];
    [test setSelectedValue:self.info[0]];
    [self presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Во втором контроллере:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *selectedValue;
```

Пример на [GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/TestDataSendToSecondVCForSO). Попробуйте, разберитесь с подходом. Содержимое примера:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *currentSelection;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *infoLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self checkSelectedSegment:_segmentedControl];
}

- (void)checkSelectedSegment:(UISegmentedControl *) segmentedControl {
    _currentSelection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Значение %ld", segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [_infoLabel setText:_currentSelection];
}

- (IBAction)onSegmetChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    [self checkSelectedSegment:sender];
}

- (IBAction)goToNextControllerAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondController = (SecondViewController *)[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [secondController setSelectedValue:_currentSelection];
    [self presentViewController:secondController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *selectedValue;

@end

#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *infoLabel;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (IBAction)checkValueAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    [_infoLabel setText:_selectedValue];
}

- (IBAction)closeAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```